# __dirname unexpected in development with Webpack, React and Electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, electron

- Electron: 13.5.2
- Webpack: 5.70.0
- React: 18.1.0

```js
console.log(__dirname);
```

I was expecting something like:

`C:Users\...\Project\app\settings`

But the output:

`...\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `__dirname` shows the **directory** not the **file** so you shouldn't expect it to show a file.

Second `__dirname` shows directory name of the **module** that is currently run. Electron is starting the process, not your code.

Comment: Because the main `.js` file that is run by `node` is in electron directory

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213696/how-can-i-get-the-path-that-the-application-is-running-with-typescript